# React Apex Chart Data, Image and API

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, apexcharts

How to modify series and options, i want to make chart type=treemap on react hooks like this

[image]

i have name, user and percent on api.

```
  {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Pisces",
            "user": "95",
            "percent": "3.15%",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Leo",
            "user": "50",
            "percent": "2.35%",
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Capricorn",
            "user": "91",
            "percent": "3.12%",
        }
        ]
    }
```

and source for apex https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/treemap-chart/

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import Chart from 'react-apexcharts'
import icUser from './image/profile-user.png'
import icChart from './image/pie-chart.png'

const  App =()=> {
  const [dataUser,setDataUser]=useState([])
  useEffect(() => {    
     axios.get("http://localhost:4000/data")
      .then(response =>{
          setDataUser(response.data)
      }).catch(e => {
          alert(e);
      })
  }, [])
  
 const series = {.....}
 const options = {.....}

 return (
     <div>
     <Chart options={options} series={series} height={350} type="treemap"/>
     </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

Comment: Can you explain more... about your question !

Answer (score 1):

In `series` you need to pass an array like this, Where `x` is the name, and `y` percentage. and In `option` you can modify the treemap chart like change `height`, `type`, `plotOptions` and more...

```
const App = () => {
  const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/data")
      .then(response => {
        setDataUser(response.data)
      }).catch(e => {
        alert(e);
      })
  }, [])

  const seriesData = [];
  const options = {}

  dataUser.map((val) => {
    seriesData.push(
      {
        x: val.name,   //
        y: val.percent  //
      }
    );
  });

  const series = [{ data: seriesData }];
  return (
    <div>
      <Chart options={options} series={series} height={350} type="treemap" />
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: how we can put the data from API on series, i have name, user and percent on API

Comment: I update my answer,  you need to put your data in array pls check

Comment: thanks, now i can show the name, but not yet for user and percent like the picture above

Comment: You can show user or percentage in `Y`

Comment: you can pass only two parameter in data array `x and y` !

Comment: yes i can show percent Y on popup. i want to show like the picture. is this related to the formatter on datalabels in options? here, a little information about it https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/treemap-charts/color-range/

Comment: I read this documentation ! i am unable to find this option